# How do you set the time of a transfer when testing contracts with SmartPy?

Tags: smartpy, testing

Previously, to set the (virtual) time a transaction happened in SmartPy I used the flag `now` when running a command like `run`. Now it seems to cause an error (seems like something changed in an update). What is the new way to perform the equivalent command?

Note that in this example, `c1` is the name of the contract, `merchClaim` is the name of the entrypoint, and `bob` is the name of an account.

```
Error: 'int' object has no attribute 'export'

Traceback (most recent call last):

 SmartPy code line 299, in test (line 299)
   scenario += c1.merchClaim().run(sender = bob, now = 10, valid = False)
 module smartpy line 1103, in run
   result.time = self.smartml.time.export()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `now = sp.timestamp(10)`.

We used to allow `now = 10` but this is not well typed.

(also, obviously, the exception message should be better)